# Getting NullReferenceException when trying to deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, serialization

so I'm trying to wrap my head around how to deserialize this properly.

```
{
  "_note": "You are currently authenticated with the API using your OPSkins login session cookies.",
  "status": 1,
  "time": 1500460072,
  "response": {
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)": {
      "op_7_day": 999,
      "op_30_day": 932
    },
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)": {
      "op_7_day": 2738,
      "op_30_day": 2665
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my class structure

```
public class OpRoot
{
    public string _note { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public OpResponse response { get; set; }
}

public class OpResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string, OpItem> items { get; set; }
}

public class OpItem
{
    public int op_7_day { get; set; }
    public int op_30_day { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to deserialize it:

```
OpRoot OpInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpRoot>(readerResponse);
```

I have tried to change the Dictionary into a List instead, but got the same result "System.NullReferenceException" when trying to call the "items" object:

```
Console.WriteLine(OpInstance.response.items.Values);
```

So I think the problem lies within the code of the "OpResponse" class. Most of this code has worked before, however with another JSON structure.

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT: Fixed typo

Comment: The JSON is malformed, Json always starts with a `{`

Comment: Your JSON format is not correct. Check positions for braces({}).

Comment: This was a typo in the post, fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `OpResponse`. With the following classes it should work:

```
public class OpRoot
{
   public string _note { get; set; }
   public int status { get; set; }
   public int time { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, OpItem> response { get; set; }
}

public class OpItem
{
   public int op_7_day { get; set; }
   public int op_30_day { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can eliminate one class entirely- I'd honestly store `OpItem` with its own string name, but that's just me:

```
public class OpRoot
{
    public string _note { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public List<OpItem> {get; set;}
}

public class OpItem
{
    public int op_7_day { get; set; }
    public int op_30_day { get; set; }
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Or, if you can't change the json you get, you could take the other answer.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as a typographical error unless this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: My fault! The JSON I posted here was cut from a much longer JSON, and I accidently forgot to include the two brackets in this post. Fixed the typo now, and the error still occurs

Comment: I don't see anything explicitly named `items` in your json, why is that?

Comment: It would be a lot easier for you in terms of JSON format if you stored them as a List. Unless you have a billion of them, a list will do fine and it'll make your JSON a bit easier.